# How to set arguments for Google Closure Compiler web version?

Tags: google-closure-compiler

I am trying to figure out how to set an argument for Google Closure Compiler at 
https://closure-compiler.appspot.com/

For example `--jscomp_off=es5Strict` or one of others:
https://gist.github.com/mshafrir/816686

I assume I need to add arguments somewhere here:

```
// ==ClosureCompiler==
// @compilation_level SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS
// @output_file_name default.js
// ==/ClosureCompiler==
```

If yes, in what format? If, no where else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full reference is on [the wiki](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Additional-Webservice-Options)

Not all of the options available on the compiler are supported by the web service.

Comment: I came to stackoverflow after I have reread that for a few times and failed to find any way to add arguments to the web version, what arguments are available and what the syntax is. I have found `// @language` elsewhere random without it even being specified as being a possible argument to the web version, but I tried it and it worked. The link you posted only includes the info for the API version, nothing useful for the UI version (as they call it).

Comment: @Alph.Dev I had pasted the wrong link. I've corrected it now.

Comment: This is it! Thank you.